# Export row level variable labels, value labels and value

Tags: spss

Somewhat new to SPSS and wondering if its possible to export into an excel file a data map containing the variable label, value label and corresponding value at a row level. I know you can download a data map via Display Data File Information but the variable label is a header rather than displayed on each row.

Example...

```
  “what is your gender”,”male”,”1”
  “what is your gender”,”female”,”2”
  "primary car brand","Chevy","1"
  "primary car brand","Buick","2"
  "primary car brand","Fiat","3"
  "primary car brand","Toyota","4"
  "primary car brand","Kia","5"
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See whether the CODEBOOK (Analyze > Reports > Codebook) procedure is more to your liking.  Any Viewer table can be exported to Excel either via File > Export or using OMS.  Or the exact format of the display you showed can be produced as a table using Python programmability.  Details if you need to go that way.

In many use cases, the APPLY DICTIONARY (Data > Copy Data Properties) does what's needed without the need to create an external listing.

Comment: OMS worked for me.  This question is pretty similar to mine and OMS worked for me.  Check it out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524233/vars-to-cases-retain-variable-value-labels-tableau-setup-restructure-data-fo

Comment: @JKP            Thanks for the feedback. Between your comment and Nick Z's I was able to stitch the pieces I need together.